# If you make it public, you are obligated to support it forever to maintain compatibility

Tags: java, interface

I'm reading *Effective Java* and I have some confusion about statement -

> If you make an interface `public`, you are obligated to support it
>   forever to maintain compatibility

can anyone tell me some reason ?

Comment: If an API is public, clients will come to depend on it. You therefore can't really remove it without upsetting client code that's dependent on it. If you do remove it then you're damned as client code can no longer depend on your API - you will prevent clients upgrading to your newer versions until they've accommodated your changes.

Comment: Hmm, it clear for me now . Effective java is  an awesome book .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author means that if you release a product and folks get used to it, and you change it, you'll break whatever it is they've done to their program to make it work with your program/API.  Here is the statement's context:

> By making it a private-package, and you can modify it, replace it, or
>   eliminate it in a subsequent release *without fear of harming existing
>   clients*.  If you make an interface public, you are obligated to
>   support it forever to maintain compatibility. [emphasis mine]